# There is a way to detect the "delete-event" of a custom GtkWidget?

Tags: events, gtk

While writing my `Gtk` application, I have encountered a problem.

My app has a single `GtkNotebook` where the user can add and remove pages dynamically. All the pages contains some custom widget.

When the user removes a single page from the `GtkNotebook`, I need some trick to properly detect the `delete-event` signal (and/or the `destroy` signal) of the custom widget - not the page itself - just a moment before the widget is destroyed.

Is there some way to do this?

Strangely, I have not found a way to capture the removal of a page from the `GtkNotebook` either

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the widget's `destroy` signal?

Answer (score 1):

The correct signal to connect to is the `destroy` signal.

When you create the page, you just need to use `g_signal_connect (custom_widget, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (my_destroy_callback), userdata);` like you normally would to listen to a signal.

As for the signal related to the removal of a `GtkNotebook` page there is `page-removed`: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkNotebook.html#GtkNotebook-page-removed